# Proving the Bourbaki–Witt Theorem using Recursion.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to prove the Bourbaki–Witt theorem, which states:

> Let $\left(X,\leq\right)$ be a partially ordered set and let
>   $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a function. Suppose that $f\left(x\right)\geq x$
>   for all $x\in X$ and that every chain in $X$ has a supremum.  Then for
>   all $x\in X$, there exists an element $y\in Y$ such that $y\geq x$ and
>   $f\left(y\right)=y$.

There is more than one way to prove this theorem. The method I want to use involves Hartogs Lemma (there exists an ordinal which does not inject to a given set) and transfinite recursion. The proofs I have seen start by recursively defining a function as follows:

[image]

This is from the following proofwiki article: [Bourbaki–Witt theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bourbaki-Witt_Fixed_Point_Theorem)
.

First of all, I am uncomfortable with how they defined $g$. It's not rigorous enough for me. My goal is to define $g$ more rigorously/precisely using the recursion theorem. This is the version of the recursion theorem that I will use:

> Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal, let $Y$ be a non-empty set, and let $a\in Y$.
>   Let $g:Y\rightarrow Y$ be a function and let
>   $h:\wp\left(Y\right)\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Then there exists a
>   unique function $\varphi:\alpha\rightarrow Y$ such that
>
> • $\varphi\left(\emptyset\right)=a$,
>
> •
>   $\varphi\left(\beta^{+}\right)=g\left(\varphi\left(\beta\right)\right)$
>   for all $\beta\in\alpha$ with $\beta^{+}\in\alpha$, and
>
> • $\varphi\left(\gamma\right)=h\left(\varphi\left[\gamma\right]\right)$
>   for every limit ordinal $\gamma\in\alpha$.

By $\beta^{+}$, I mean the immediate successor of the ordinal $\beta$ and by $\wp\left(Y\right)$, I mean the power set of $Y$. Also, $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ is the set $\left\{ \varphi\left(\beta\right):\beta\in\gamma\right\} $.

Is this version of the Recursion Theorem sufficient to define $g$? I know that there are many different versions of the recursion theorem that may be more appropriate than this one. Now using this recursive definition, I will try to define the function $g$ used in the proofwiki article, which I will just label  $\varphi$:

> Let $x\in X$ and let $\alpha$ be an ordinal such that there does not exist an injection from $\alpha$ to $X$. Let
>   $h:\wp\left(X\right)\rightarrow X$ be any function such that for all
>   $A\in\wp\left(X\right)$, if $A$ is a chain in $X$, then $h\left(A\right)=\sup A$
>    . By the Recursion Theorem above, there exists
>   a unique function $\varphi:\alpha\rightarrow X$ such that
>
> • $\varphi\left(\emptyset\right)=x$,
>
> •
>   $\varphi\left(\beta^{+}\right)=f\left(\varphi\left(\beta\right)\right)$
>   for all $\beta\in\alpha$ with $\beta^{+}\in\alpha$, and
>
> • $\varphi\left(\gamma\right)=h\left(\varphi\left[\gamma\right]\right)$
>   for every limit ordinal $\gamma\in\alpha$.

This is how I started the proof. Now evidently, the function $\varphi$ is *apparently* not the function required. I need to show that if $\gamma\in\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ is a chain in $X$. That will guarantee that $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ will have a supremum. I will then have obtained the function in the proofwiki article. This is the part that I am having trouble with. The proofwiki article stated that indeed this is the case and follows from the fact that $f\left(x\right)\geq x$
 for all $x\in X$. However, this is not at all obvious to me. How can I show that $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ is a chain in $X$ for every limit ordinal $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is known as inflationary iff for any $x, f(x)\geqslant x$. So it is obvious that $f$ inflationary implies $\varphi(\beta)$ increasing (as mentioned in proofwiki ) for 
$$
\varphi(\beta^+)=f(\varphi(\beta))\geqslant \varphi(\beta)
$$
Also $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ is clearly a chain for $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$
$$
\varphi[\gamma_1]=\{\varphi(\beta):\beta<\gamma_1\} \subset \{\varphi(\beta):\beta<\gamma_2\}=\varphi[\gamma_2]
$$
If $\alpha$ is limit ordinal, then for $\gamma_1<\gamma_2<\cdots<\alpha$
$$
\varphi[\gamma_1]\subset\varphi[\gamma_2]\subset\cdots\subset\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha}\varphi[\gamma]=\sup_{\gamma<\alpha}\varphi[\gamma]
$$
So we can define $\quad h(\varphi[\gamma])=\sup_{\gamma<\alpha}\varphi[\gamma]$.

Comment: I still don't understand how $\varphi[\gamma]$ is a chain exactly, that is, if two elements $a,b$ are in it, either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$.

Comment: For any $\beta\in\gamma_1, \beta\in\gamma_2$ for $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$, i.e. $\varphi(\beta)\in\varphi[\gamma_1]\implies\varphi(\beta)\in\varphi[\gamma_2]$. So $\varphi[\gamma_1]\subset\varphi[\gamma_2]$. If $\gamma_2<\gamma_1$, then $\varphi[\gamma_2]\subset\varphi[\gamma_1]$

Comment: But $\varphi[\gamma_1]$ and $\varphi[\gamma_2]$ are not elements of $\varphi[\gamma]$, they are subsets of it.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. $φ[γ]$ is subset ($\wp\left(Y\right)$ is power set). Look at definition,  $h:\wp\left(Y\right)\rightarrow Y$ for $\varphi\left(\gamma\right)=h\left(\varphi\left[\gamma\right]\right)$

Comment: I do understand that $\varphi[\gamma]$ is a subset of $Y$, and I understand that either $\varphi[\gamma_1]\subseteq\varphi[\gamma_2]$ or $\varphi[\gamma_2]\subseteq\varphi[\gamma_1]$ for any $\gamma_1 ,\gamma_2 \in \gamma$. I just don't get how that shows that  $\varphi[\gamma]$ is a chain.

Comment: Normally sets are partially ordered, not linearly ordered. So for 2 sets $A$ and $B$, there are 3 possibilities, $A\subset B, B\subset A$ or neither. But it is either $φ[γ_1]⊆φ[γ_2]$ or $φ[γ_2]⊆φ[γ_1]$, no other possibility. So $φ[γ]$ is a chain, i.e. linearly ordered.

Comment: What you've shown is that the set $\left\{ \varphi\left[\beta\right]:\beta\in\gamma\right\}$  is a chain, but I want to show that $\varphi\left[\gamma\right]$ is a chain.

Comment: Yes but $\left\{ \varphi\left[\beta\right]:\beta\in\gamma\right\} \neq \left\{ \varphi\left(\beta\right):\beta\in\gamma\right\}$.

Comment: How did you show that $\{φ(β):β∈γ\}=φ[γ]$ is a chain? You just showed that for any $β_{1},β_{2}, \in \gamma $, either $φ[β_{1}] \subseteq φ[β_{2}]$ or $φ[β_{2}] \subseteq φ[β_{1}]$.

Comment: It looks like we're going in circles now, so I don't see any benefit in continuing this conversation. Thank you for attempting to answer the question.